# Is there any method replace repeating pattern specifically in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a some string which have word and number.

```
[1] "\r\nfund \r\ncompany \r\nfee \r\nsales \r\ngroup \r\npayment \r\nmanagement \r\nfirm \r\nfee \r\ntotal \r\npayment \r\nsubtotal \r\nfee \r\nsynthetic \r\nfee... sth ... \r\n0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253....
```

As you can see there is a pattern which have sth~ fee, sth~ payment. 
My ultimate goal is to group the words to make this table using scan function or else(if you have any idea please reply with this.)

So I tried to delete all the blank because scan function (i guess) identify with some blank as standard to divide words group.

Again I mean, I want to make this string like this

```
[1] "\r\nfundcompanyfee \r\nsalesgrouppayment \r\nmanagementfirmfee \r\ntotalpayment \r\nsubtotalfee \r\nsyntheticfee... sth ... \r\n0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253....
```

I tried to use gsub function like this

```
 gsub("\r\n\\w\\w.*?fee|payment","\\w\\w",strings)
```

but the result was awful. it makes string like this

```
ww ww ww ww........ 0.646 0.030 0.030 ....
```

that is it doesn't recognize \w as word.. just translate it to 'w' as it is!

So I need some help to deal with this.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Could probably be simplified but it works:

```r
library(stringr)

strings <- "\r\nfund \r\ncompany \r\nfee \r\nsales \r\ngroup \r\npayment \r\nmanagement \r\nfirm \r\nfee \r\ntotal \r\npayment \r\nsubtotal \r\nfee \r\nsynthetic \r\nfee \r\n0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253"

# values
values <- stringr::str_extract_all(strings, "\\d+\\.\\d+")[[1]]
values <- paste0("\r\n", paste(values, collapse = " "))
# categories
categories <- stringr::str_extract_all(strings, "(\\r\\n\\w+\\s){1,2}\\r\\n(fee|payment)")[[1]] 
categories <- stringr::str_replace_all(categories, "(\\r\\n|\\s)", "")
categories <- paste(paste0("\r\n", categories), collapse = " ")
# merge
strings1 <- paste(categories, values)
strings1
#> [1] "\r\nfundcompanyfee \r\nsalesgrouppayment \r\nmanagementfirmfee \r\ntotalpayment \r\nsubtotalfee \r\nsyntheticfee \r\n0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
library(tidyverse)
strings <- "\r\nfund \r\ncompany \r\nfee \r\nsales \r\ngroup \r\npayment \r\nmanagement \r\nfirm \r\nfee \r\ntotal \r\npayment \r\nsubtotal \r\nfee \r\nsynthetic \r\nfee \r\n0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253"

strings %>% 
 gsub("\r\n", "", .) %>% 
 gsub("fee", "fee$", .) %>% 
 gsub("payment", "payment$", .) %>% 
 str_split(., pattern = "\\$", simplify = T) %>% 
 toString() %>% 
 gsub(",","\r\n", .)
[1] "fund company fee\r\n  sales group payment\r\n  management firm fee\r\n  total payment\r\n  subtotal fee\r\n  synthetic fee\r\n ... sth ... 0.646 0.030 0.030 0.015 1.253...."
```

Simply add this line `gsub(" ", "", .) %>%` after the split function if you want to remove spaces between the words.